# how to convert date to day of week using momentjs and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have dates in this format in my json
"26 Feb 2015 00:00:00" which I would like to be converted to day of the week ie Tue
This seems straightforward using momentjs but my question is how to call the momentjs format() method inside html vs. inside the <script>
I guess I can create a new json string inside the script but would like to avoid that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
    <table>
    <tr><th>day</th><th>value</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="tsval in data['key']">
      <td>{{tsval.timestamp }}</td>
      <td>{{ tsval.val }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
   <script>
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
      'key':[
        {
            'timestamp':'26 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
            'val':'v1'
        },
        {
            'timestamp':'27 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
            'val':'v2'
        },
        {
            'timestamp':'28 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
            'val':'v3'
        }
      ]
    };
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a custom filter that wraps `moment().format()`

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = '28 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT'; 
})
.filter('format', function() {
  return function(input, format) {
    return moment(new Date(input)).format(format);
  };
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>{{myDate | format:'ddd'}}</p>
</div>
```

You can also just use Angular's built in `date` filter for this, but it doesn't like your date format, so you'd have to apply another filter to convert it to an ISO string first. If you don't need momentjs for any other reason, I'd get rid of it and just do this.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = '28 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT'; 
})
.filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return new Date(input).toISOString();
  };
})
;
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>{{myDate | dateToISO | date:'EEE'}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a helper function to the scope that formats the provided date as a day.

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    'key': [{
      'timestamp': '26 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
      'val': 'v1'
    }, {
      'timestamp': '27 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
      'val': 'v2'
    }, {
      'timestamp': '28 Feb 2015 00:00:00 GMT',
      'val': 'v3'
    }]
  };

  $scope.toDay = function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('ddd');
  };
});
```

And in your template, fire the helper off and pass the date as the argument.

```
<td>{{ toDay(tsval.timestamp) }}</td>
```

This renders:

```
day value
Wed v1
Thu v2
Fri v3
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gdu2Ag32VmtKwKxJdNSm)

Comment: The OP asked how he could change it in the html. He wanted to avoid do this. Also, it makes more sense as a filter anyway, noted by the fact that Angular has date filters already. momentjs just offers more in that regard.

Comment: I think you've misread... the OP asked how to format the date with three characters in the HTML vs the script. This achieves that and avoids his concern to "create a new json string inside the script". While a filter makes sense as well, and the OP wanted to use moment which this does, and it works just fine.

Comment: `call the momentjs format() method inside html` sounds like a filter to me, but it's all good. Just wanted to give you a heads up in case.

Comment: Both answers work great. I chose the other simply because i saw it first. But this approach is slightly more readable than the other though.

Comment: @alek I would think in the long term, I'm not sure why you like this approach better, but even with that, you have to consider that it isn't reusable anywhere else. You want to avoid hardcoding things into controllers, so a service or a filter are the way to go. With that in mind, you can inject a filter into a controller just like you can a service, so you'd only be limiting yourself making it a service. With a filter, you can use it in your html or in your controller.

Comment: Oh and Seth, I didn't mean to draw anything away from the merit of your answer. It's worth noting that your approach gets the job done. I just want to help the OP mature in his architecture as much as possible.

Comment: All good. Your examples are great and I agree in regards to maturity.